# Cannot find postgres table created using python program

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I wrote a python program to create a postgres table and populate it with some data.Here is the code below

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="metrics", user="souvik", password="*******", host="localhost", port="5432")
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS device_mse(date date,metric character varying(255),device character varying(255),mse double precision);")
insert_statement = "INSERT INTO device_mse VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s);"
cur.executemany(insert_statement, result)
```

The program runs successfully and doesn't throw any error.However in the postgres command line when I search for the table in the database `metrics` using `\dt`, it doesn't show up.

I even tried `/d+ device_mse` but it says no relation found.What is going wrong?

Comment: Missing `commit` in your program?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ah!exactly!Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @a_horse_with_no_name, I forgot to add a `commit` statement to the program because of which the table was never created.

**Updated code**

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="metrics", user="souvik", password="*******", host="localhost", port="5432")
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS device_mse(date date,metric character varying(255),device character varying(255),mse double precision);")
insert_statement = "INSERT INTO device_mse VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s);"
cur.executemany(insert_statement, result)
cur.commit()
```